# OSMBuilding with MapBox key

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js

Looking at the example here: https://osmbuildings.org/examples/

In the JS section they define event for click:

```
 osmb.click(function(e) {
  var url = 'https://data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/uejws863/feature/'+ e.feature +'.json';
  ajax(url, function(json) {
    var content = '<b>OSM ID '+ e.feature +'</b>';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.features.length; i++) {
      content += '<br><em>OSM Part ID</em> '+ json.features[i].id;
      content += '<br>'+ formatJSON(json.features[i].properties.tags);
    }

    L.popup({ maxHeight:200, autoPanPaddingTopLeft:[50,50] })
      .setLatLng(L.latLng(e.lat, e.lon))
      .setContent(content)
      .openOn(map);
  });
});
```

In this code uejws863 is "YOUR_MAPBOX_KEY". I can find my MAPBOX access token but it still says "unauthorized" if i change uej.. with my token.
Basically i'm trying to run this example on localhost.
What should i do next to find the key or change api call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at OSM Buildings [examples](https://osmbuildings.org/developer/) the `"YOUR_MAPBOX_KEY"` is used when making tile requests to MapBox servers, like:

```
map.addMapTiles('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[YOUR_MAPBOX_KEY]/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
```

When making requests to OSM Buildings servers they are using `anonymous` as a key:

```
map.addGeoJSONTiles('https://{s}.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.json');
```

Although I´m getting results with the `anonymous`key, for example:

https://data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/style.json

I suggest you to register to get a key from OSM Buildings, not from MapBox

https://osmbuildings.org/login/